# Weblogic 12.2.1.3 Error: Could not find or load main class com.oracle.cie.wizard.WizardController

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

I was trying to configure Weblogic 12.2.1.3 on Linux account.
After going through oracle documentation, I understood we setup Weblogic by running config.sh script located in `/opt/weblogic12213/wlserver_12.2.1.3/installation/oracle_common/common/bin` folder.

But this script is giving error as :

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   com.oracle.cie.wizard.WizardController

Below is the last command which it executes in setup script and it is giving an error :

> /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_192/bin/java -Dpython.cachedir=/tmp/cachedir
>   -Xms32m -Xmx1024m -Dweblogic.alternateTypesDirectory=/opt/weblogic12213/wlserver_12.2.1.3/installation/wlserver/../oracle_common/modules/oracle.oamprovider,/opt/weblogic12213/wlserver_12.2.1.3/installation/wlserver/../oracle_common/modules/oracle.jps
>   com.oracle.cie.wizard.WizardController -target=config-oneclick

Comment: Hello!! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read the description of a tag before applying it on your question. I have removed the tag 'oracle' as the description of this tag is: 'Oracle Database is a Multi-Model Database Management System created by Oracle Corporation. Do NOT use this tag for other products owned by Oracle, such as Java and MySQL'

Answer (score 0):

scripts provided by weblogic doesn't set CLASSPATH correctly.

com.oracle.cie.wizard.WizardController comes under com.oracle.cie.wizard_7.8.2.0.jar .

Steps done.
 1. Copied config_internal.sh script on some local path. (Because I didn't have the root permission.)
 2. Appended this jar in CLASSPATH varibale like this :

```
CLASSPATH="${FMWCONFIG_CLASSPATH}${CLASSPATHSEP}${DERBY_CLASSPATH}:/opt/weblogic12213/wlserver_12.2.1.3/installation/oracle_common/modules/com.oracle.cie.wizard_7.8.2.0.jar"
```

Comment: I couldn't replicate the issue, the config.sh worked as expected, but I was wondering why you mentioned the root permissions. Note that WLS shouldn't be installed with root account, but a non-administrative account. If WLS is installed with the root account and then you tried to execute the scripts with a non-administrative account, probably you'll find some runtime error.